# Automate Android Espresso test cases using Jenkins

Tags: android, unit-testing, jenkins, sdk, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to automate android espresso test cases using Jenkins pipeline on mac mini, we have pipeline up and running for Android build and sonar test cases are not included. I have installed SDK created AVD and Emulators as well but unfortunately I'm not able to make it run the test cases.
(environment variables JDK, Android SDK, Gradle, Git in Jenkins config is all setup correctly)

Is there any blog/Article that can help me to setup the pipeline cause I'm running out of options, I googled but no luck, found some articles but those were outdated.

Please suggest if you have any ideas or if you have worked/working on same scenario..!!

Comment: Try to set environment variables JDK, Android SDK, Gradle, Git in Jenkins config. then it should see all tests which u have in ur app.

Comment: We have written test cases and I want those test cases to run on AVD.